# afterInsert, afterUpdate JMS

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a running grails application where I want to add some functionality.
I would like to do  after an object has been inserted, updated or deleted into the database.

What I think of is triggering a JMS event "person.inserted",  "person.updated" with the respective ID as a parameter. When I catch the event I want to do something with the Object.

Hence I want to retrieve it from the database. I am having problems retrieving the Object from the DB.

```
  DomainObject.get(<id>)
```

It's null.

I am testing with the

```
 afterInsert
```

event. So I assumed the data is already in the Database. Is there a better way to do that? Any working example?

Comment: Let me repose my question: What is the correct post commit hook that is triggered after the Domain Object is written to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your transaction has not been committed yet, when the JMS consumer receives the event. You may want to use a retry strategy when the object is not found, waiting a couple of seconds until the next try.

You are mentioning tests. Are you using unit tests, or functional/integration tests? Maybe manual? You could add a sleep in your subscriber before you attempt loading the object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To answer your question: I am at the moment testing manually. I don't want to use a sleep this seems to be "very dirty" way of fixing it. What happens under heavy load the query takes longe and the time I am sleeping is too short.

Comment: I was not suggesting to use this technique as a solution, but as a way to find out if your issue is a timing issue.

Comment: Ah ok understood. Thanks for that one.